# Why does postgres say operator does not exist: json ? unknown

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have the following query which I'm trying to run against my postgres database:

```
select distinct offer_id from offers
    where listing_id = 2299392
    group by offer_id
    having not bool_or(status in ('Rejected', 'Draft') or (status = 'Pending' and expiry_date < now())
        or (seller_t_and_c_accepted = true and buyer_t_and_c_accepted = true and
            (   (seller_conditions = null and buyer_conditions = null) -- neither buyer nor seller have any conditions
                -- seller has conditions and they are all done
                or (buyer_conditions = null and not exists (select * from json_each(offers.seller_conditions::json) as sc(key,val) where (sc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or sc.val ? 'done'))
                -- buyer has conditions and they are all done
                or (seller_conditions = null and not exists (select * from json_each(offers.buyer_conditions::json) as bc(key,val) where (bc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or bc.val ? 'done'))
                -- both buyer and seller have conditions and they are all done
                or (not exists (select * from json_each(offers.buyer_conditions::json) as bc(key,val) where (bc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or sc.val ? 'done') and not exists (select * from json_each(offers.seller_conditions::json) as sc(key,val) where (sc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or sc.val ? 'done'))
            )
        )
    )
```

I'm getting the error:

```
operator does not exist: json ? unknown
```

This happens when I add the following pieces to the above query:

```
sc.val ? 'done'

...

bc.val ? 'done'
```

I'm no sql or postgres expert, but I *think* json_object ? 'field' is supposed to returns true if 'field' is the name of a field that exists in the json object, and false otherwise (i.e. if it doesn't exist in the json object).

I don't think you need to know what I'm trying to accomplish in the query above but it might help, so I'll break it down for you.

I'm trying to get all active offers for a given real estate listing (in this case, listing with id 2299392). An active offer on a listing is an offer that is not rejected, not in draft, not expired, and not complete. A 'complete' offer is an offer in which both the buyer and the seller have accepted the terms and conditions and all the buyer's conditions (if any) are met and all the seller's conditions (if any) are met.

It's the conditions for a 'complete' offer in the query above that are most convoluted, so I'll break that down further. It starts with this:

```
...or (seller_t_and_c_accepted = true and buyer_t_and_c_accepted = true and
```

Buyer and seller have both accepted the terms and conditions...

```
(   (seller_conditions = null and buyer_conditions = null) or ...
```

covers the case where neither the buyer nor the seller have any conditions.

```
(buyer_conditions = null and not exists (select * from json_each(offers.seller_conditions::json) as sc(key,val) where (sc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or sc.val ? 'done')) or...
```

covers the case where the buyer has no conditions but the seller does. The conditions are stored as a json object:

```
{
  "Subject to financing": {"date": "2020-03-19", "time": "2100", "done": false},
  "Subject to inspection": {"date": "2020-03-19", "time": "2100", "done": true}
}
```

It's essentially a series of conditions, each of which is itself a json object consisting of a deadline (date and time) and whether or not it has been met (done).

In order to parse through this to see if all conditions are met, I have a nested select:

```
select * from json_each(offers.seller_conditions::json) as sc(key,val) where (sc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or sc.val ? 'done'
```

I am looping through all conditions with json_each and getting key/value pairs (so the key might be "subject to financing" and the value is {"date": "2020-03-19", "time": "2100", "done": false}). Then I'm checking the value to see if the 'done' field is false (meaning this condition is not satisfied and therefore belongs in my results). I also check that the value HAS a field called 'done' (because sometimes it won't, as in: {"date": "2020-03-19", "time": "2100"}). <-- It's this part which is throwing the error: operator does not exist: json ? unknown.

Anyway, the rest is more of the same:

```
(seller_conditions = null and not exists (select * from json_each(offers.buyer_conditions::json) as bc(key,val) where (bc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or bc.val ? 'done')) or ...
```

covers the case where the seller has no conditions but the buyer does, and:

```
(not exists (select * from json_each(offers.buyer_conditions::json) as bc(key,val) where (bc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or sc.val ? 'done') and not exists (select * from json_each(offers.seller_conditions::json) as sc(key,val) where (sc.val -> 'done')::text = 'false' or sc.val ? 'done'))
```

covers the case where both the buyer and the seller have conditions.

Anyway, does anyone see why it would tell me that the ? operator does not exist? Am I writing it wrong? Is there another way of accomplishing what I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ? operator is only defined for jsonb, not for json.  Notice the docs have two tables, one for dual typed operators and one for jsonb only.

You will need to cast the value to jsonb.  Ideally you would change the column type to jsonb, then use jsonb operators/functions all the way down.

Comment: Thanks, jjanes... casting the columns to jsonb (and using jsonb_each) works.